# \titlecaps in figure's captions containing mathematical expressions

Tags: titlecaps

How can we use `\titlecaps` to get the right figure's and table's captions IF these captions contain mathematical expressions ?

Based on a suggestion made in this website, I have added in my LaTeX file:

```
%%% set figure captions to use titlecaps

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\titlecap{#1}}

\captionsetup[figure]{textformat=up}

\captionsetup[table]{textformat=up}
```

but I get compilation errors for a caption like this one:

```
\caption{Simulations performed with k-$\omega$ SST and DDES-SST}
```

because of the expression `k-$\omega$` in the caption.

-----  Version 2 --------------

Thank you for this first answer and sorry for having not provided a complete LaTeX document !

Here is a better example where I think that there is a conflict between `\titlecaps` and `\bm`.

(1) If the lines concerning `titlecaps` modifications are commented, the command `\bm` works fine

(2) If these lines are active, there is a compilation error when `\bm` is added and everything works fine if I do not have the bold Greek symbol.
I hope this is now more clear. Thank you for your help !

---

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

 \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

 \usepackage{titlecaps}

 \usepackage{caption}

 \usepackage{bm}

%%% CUSTOM STYLE FOR CHAPTER HEADLINES

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{article}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{3.5ex}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3.3ex}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} % removes word chapter from chapter number
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large\titlecap{##1}} % title caps for chapter headings
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \@hangfrom{\chapnumfont \thechapter\quad}}%
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{article}

%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUB-SUBSECTIONS
 
 \maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, subsections numbered

% set section headings to titlecaps
\newcommand\sectioncaps[1]{%
  \bfseries\raggedright\titlecap{#1}%
}
% set subsection headings to titlecaps
\newcommand\subsectioncaps[1]{%
  \bfseries\raggedright\titlecap{#1}%
}
\setsecheadstyle{\sectioncaps}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\subsectioncaps}

%%% set figure captions to use titlecaps

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\titlecap{#1}}
\captionsetup[figure]{textformat=up}

\settypeblocksize{237mm}{150mm}{*} % size of text block on page
\setulmargins{3.5cm}{*}{*} % sets start of text on page after ruled header
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{2cm}{*}{*} % start of rule header line on page
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % left and right margins
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a nice chapter title it should be titlecaps}

\section{A first section title and should also be titlecaps}

\subsection{A subsection title, also in titlecaps}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[htb]

    \centering

%    \caption{This is a text for a caption and should be title caps with $\bm{\omega}$} % is not working

    \caption{This is a text for a caption and should be title caps with $\omega$} % is OK

    \label{fig:my_label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide a complete compilable example which produces the error and tell us which error you get. Code snippets are rarely helpful. Linking to the original suggestion would also be good. Did it really recommend doing this for cases where maths is involved?

Comment: I cannot recreate the error.  Please provide a short, but complete example, rather than a code snippet.

Comment: I have posted a simple LaTeX example to illustrate the apparent conflict between titlecaps and bm for figure and table captions. Thank you for your help !

Comment: With your provided example, my compilation works as expected.  What version of `titlecaps` are you loading? Mine is `titlecaps 2022/04/12 version 1.3`